# How to Add Controller In Angular Directive Class In Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-directive, angular-controller

Following is my angular directive class in typescript I have written so far:

My question is how I can add controller for this directive. I don't want to create new controller class and bind that controller with controller. I want to **write the controller and inject the ISOLATE SCOPE inside the directive class** in typescript

```
    module Sheet.Directive{
    class InputControl implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict = 'A';
    //require = 'ngModel';
    templateUrl = "../Templates/inputcontrol.html";



    constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService) {
    }

    link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ctrl: any) => {
        console.log(this.$location);
    };

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = ($location: ng.ILocationService) => new InputControl($location);
        directive.$inject = ['$location'];
        return directive;
    }
}

angular.module("SheetApp").directive("inputControl", InputControl.factory());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually declare property `controller` that will return a controller function, like:

```
export class App {
  restrict='E';
  templateUrl='src/app.html';
  scope = {
    a : '@'
  }
  controller = ['$scope',($scope) => {
    console.log("this this controller",$scope.a);
  }];
}
```

Here is example in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/j4coAAZ207RHyGsqFPgC (I used my `@directive` trick for more convinient declaration of directives.